# Not sure about how /?(.+) works in my regex

Tags: python, regex

I would like to capture 3 groups(protocol,domain,page path)from this URL: http://www.interactivedynamicvideo.com/ 
I made this regex pattern `pattern = r‘(\w+)://([\w.-]+)/?(.+)’`. Then, since this URL is one of data of my series, I used series.str.extract(pattern) to capture groups. I expected to get **http** for group 1, **www.interactivedynamicvideo.com** for group 2, and nothing for group 3. However, I got `/` in group 3. I thought that `/` is matched at `/?`. Could someone explain why `/` is included in `(.+)` instead of being matched at `/?` ?

Thank you for your time for this

Comment: `.+` requires at least 1  char. Change to `.*`, see https://regex101.com/r/3fCIkF/1